# Iterating over a Binary Tree with O(1) Auxiliary Space

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, tree, memory-management, binary-tree

Is it possible to iterate over a binary tree in O(1) auxiliary space (w/o using a stack, queue, etc.), or has this been proven impossible?  If it is possible, how can it be done?

Edit:  The responses I've gotten about this being possible if there are pointers to parent nodes are interesting and I didn't know that this could be done, but depending in how you look at it, that can be O(n) auxiliary space.  Furthermore, in my practical use case, there are no pointers to parent nodes.  From now on, please assume this when answering.

Comment: I consider link to parent as O(n) auxiliary space. You should edit your question to explicitly mention your binary tree doesn't have such a property.

Comment: How can you not have pointers to your parent nodes?  how can you iterate over your tree at all without them?  is that where the stack is coming in?  you will need parents pointers anyway to do balancing.

Answer (score 28):

Geez, I'll have to actually type it up from Knuth. This solution is by Joseph M. Morris [*Inf. Proc. Letters* **9** (1979), 197-200]. As far as I can tell, it runs in O(NlogN) time.

```
static void VisitInO1Memory (Node root, Action<Node> preorderVisitor) {
  Node parent = root ;
  Node right  = null ;
  Node curr ;
  while (parent != null) {
    curr = parent.left ;
    if (curr != null) {
      // search for thread
      while (curr != right && curr.right != null)
        curr = curr.right ;

      if (curr != right) {
        // insert thread
        assert curr.right == null ;
        curr.right = parent ;
        preorderVisitor (parent) ;
        parent = parent.left ;
        continue ;
      } else
        // remove thread, left subtree of P already traversed
        // this restores the node to original state
        curr.right = null ;
    } else
      preorderVisitor (parent) ;

    right  = parent ;
    parent = parent.right ;
  }
}

class Node
{
  public Node left  ;
  public Node right ;
}
```

Comment: this destroys the tree though doesn't it?

Comment: No, it just temporarily adds backreferences from certain leaves.

Comment: This solution is simply amazing.

Comment: Actually, it would be `O(n)`: You only touch a node constant number of times (note that the inner while loop only touches paths that go right and only when `curr` was the path's leftmost node's parent on entry to the outer while loop; that happens once when you enter the subtree and once you leave it. Then, `size of those paths combined = O(size of the whole tree)`.

Comment: What `assert` does? How to change it to C++?

Comment: Here's a detailed discussion of this algorithm: http://forrestyu.net/art/how-to-traverse-a-binary-tree-without-using-any-stack

Comment: How doesn't it destroy the tree? how `curr.right = null` doesn't ruin it? @Svante

Comment: @shinzou: `curr.right` was previously set to a backreference (seven lines earlier: `curr.right = parent`), setting it to `null` just restores the tree as it was before. The idea of the whole thing is that to temporarily overwrite existing null references in the data to store continuations does not constitute extra space requirements.

Comment: @Rufflewind that link is broken

Answer (score 8):

It is possible if you have a link to the parent in every child. When you encounter a child, visit the left subtree. When coming back up check to see if you're the left child of your parent. If so, visit the right subtree. Otherwise, keep going up until you're the left child or until you hit the root of the tree.

In this example the size of the stack remains constant, so there's no additional memory consumed. Of course, as Mehrdad pointed out, links to the parents can be considered O(n) space, but this is more of a property of the tree than it is a property of the algorithm.

If you don't care about the order in which you traverse the tree, you could assign an integral mapping to the nodes where the root is 1, the children of the root are 2 and 3, the children of those are 4, 5, 6, 7, etc. Then you loop through each row of the tree by incrementing a counter and accessing that node by its numerical value. You can keep track of the highest possible child element and stop the loop when your counter passes it. Time-wise, this is an extremely inefficient algorithm, but I think it takes O(1) space.

(I borrowed the idea of numbering from heaps. If you have node N, you can find the children at 2N and 2N+1. You can work backwards from this number to find the parent of a child.)

Here's an example of this algorithm in action in C. Notice that there are no malloc's except for the creation of the tree, and that there are no recursive functions which means that the stack takes constant space:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct tree
{
  int value;
  struct tree *left, *right;
} tree;

tree *maketree(int value, tree *left, tree *right)
{
  tree *ret = malloc(sizeof(tree));
  ret->value = value;
  ret->left = left;
  ret->right = right;
  return ret;
}

int nextstep(int current, int desired)
{
  while (desired > 2*current+1)
      desired /= 2;

  return desired % 2;
}

tree *seek(tree *root, int desired)
{
  int currentid; currentid = 1;

  while (currentid != desired)
    {
      if (nextstep(currentid, desired))
    if (root->right)
      {
        currentid = 2*currentid+1;
        root = root->right;
      }
    else
      return NULL;
      else
    if (root->left)
      {
        currentid = 2*currentid;
        root = root->left;
      }
    else
      return NULL;
    }
  return root;  
}


void traverse(tree *root)
{
  int counter;    counter = 1; /* main loop counter */

  /* next = maximum id of next child; if we pass this, we're done */
  int next; next = 1; 

  tree *current;

  while (next >= counter)
    {   
      current = seek(root, counter);
      if (current)
      {
          if (current->left || current->right)
              next = 2*counter+1;

          /* printing to show we've been here */
          printf("%i\n", current->value);
      }
      counter++;
    }
}

int main()
{
  tree *root1 =
    maketree(1, maketree(2, maketree(3, NULL, NULL),
                            maketree(4, NULL, NULL)),
                maketree(5, maketree(6, NULL, NULL),
                            maketree(7, NULL, NULL)));

  tree *root2 =
      maketree(1, maketree(2, maketree(3,
          maketree(4, NULL, NULL), NULL), NULL), NULL);

  tree *root3 =
      maketree(1, NULL, maketree(2, NULL, maketree(3, NULL,
          maketree(4, NULL, NULL))));

  printf("doing root1:\n");
  traverse(root1);

  printf("\ndoing root2:\n");
  traverse(root2);

  printf("\ndoing root3:\n");
  traverse(root3);
}
```

*I apologize for the quality of code - this is largely a proof of concept. Also, the runtime of this algorithm isn't ideal as it does a lot of work to compensate for not being able to maintain any state information. On the plus side, this does fit the bill of an O(1) space algorithm for accessing, in any order, the elements of the tree without requiring child to parent links or modifying the structure of the tree.*

Comment: Brian, each bit of the number will show you which direction you'd go.

Comment: But how would you access the node #7 for example without using extra space? To recurse to find such a node would take space, and if you stored all nodes in another data structure that would tkae extra space as well.

Comment: @Brian You can subtract 1 and divide by 2 to see that 3 is 7's parent. Likewise, you can subtract 1 and divide by 2 again to see that 1 is 3's parent. Therefore, all you need is a loop that will compute the next step in the path to the desired node from the current node.

Comment: @Mehrdad: Right, you may have a left heavy tree for example and this doens't work at all.

Comment: @Mehrdad Actually, all you need to do is check to see if the child exists before you try to access it, so it should work for any binary tree

Comment: @nobody_: your idea is good but you gotta note that it works only in *complete* binary trees and from a purely theoretical perspective, you still need "O(height) bit" space to store where you were.

Comment: @nobody_: No it won't work, since you are coming back from the root, you have no idea about the child count of your grandchildren

Comment: How do you get to each element at level 4?  Or for that matter level N?

Comment: @Mehrdad: Each time you access a node you traverse from the root. In that traversal you check to see if the child exists before trying to access it.

Comment: nobody_: I'm OK with that. Assume the binary tree is heavily unbalanced (just a linked list with left nodes and thus, N levels). You need O(N) bits to store the number.

Comment: @Brian: To get each element at level N you access the nodes numbered 2^(N-1) to 2^N-1 in a loop

Comment: @Mehrdad: I don't understand exactly what you mean with the bits approach, but even if it does make sense....   O(N) = O(C*N).  Even if N is 1 bi you still have O(N) space.

Comment: @nobody_: Can you give me an example of how you access the node given its number?

Comment: @Brian: "The bits approach" that I meant is exactly what you said. 2^N requires N bits for storage and is O(N) space.

Answer (score 5):

You can do it destructively, unlinking every leaf as you go.  This may be applicable in certain situations, i.e. when you don't need the tree afterwards anymore.

By extension, you could build another binary tree as you destroy the first one.  You would need some memory micromanagement to make sure that peak memory never exceeds the size of the original tree plus perhaps a little constant.  This would likely have quite some computing overhead, though.

*EDIT:*  There is a way!  You can use the nodes themselves to light the way back up the tree by temporarily reversing them.  As you visit a node, you point its `left-child` pointer to its parent, its `right-child` pointer to the last time you took a right turn on your path (which is to be found in the parent's `right-child` pointer at this moment), and store its real children either in the now-redundant parent's `right-child` pointer or in your traversal state resp. the next visited children's `left-child` pointer.  You need to keep some pointers to the current node and its vicinity, but nothing "non-local".  As you get back up the tree, you reverse the process.

I hope I could make this somehow clear; this is just a rough sketch.  You'll have to look it up somewhere (I am sure that this is mentioned somewhere in The Art of Computer Programming).

Comment: +1, I commented on this method more with a reference to your answer  in my answer.

Comment: Ingenious, but appalling.  Just have an up pointer in each element.  It is so much simpler, less painful and is well-understood and well-recognized.

Answer (score 2):

**To preserve the tree and only use O(1) space it's possible if...**

- Each node is a fixed size.
- The whole tree is in a contiguous part of memory (i.e. an array)
- You don't iterate over the tree, you simply iterate over the array

**Or if you destroy the tree as you process it...:**

- @Svante came up with this idea, but I wanted to expand on **how** a little, using a destructive approach.
- How? You can continue to take the left most **leaf** node in a tree (for(;;) node = node->left etc... , then process it, then delete it.  If the leftmost node in the tree is not a leaf node, then you process and delete the right node's left most leaf node.  If a right node has no children, then you process and delete it.

**Ways that it wouldn't work...**

If you use recursion you will use a stack implicitly.  For some algorithms (not for this problem) tail recursion would allow you to use recursion and have O(1) space, but since any particular node may have several children, and hence there is work to do after the recursive call, O(1) space tail recursion is not possible.

You could try to tackle the problem 1 level at a time, but there is no way to access an arbitrary level's nodes without auxiliary (implicit or explicit) space.   For example you could recurse to find the node you want, but then that takes implicit stack space.  Or you could store all your nodes in another data structure per level, but that takes extra space too.

Comment: You are wrong, Knuth TAOCP I.2.3.1 exercise 21 refers to at least three algorithms for tree traversal in O(1) space without destroying the original tree (although they do modify it temporarily in-place).

Comment: @nobody_: I didn't take into account cases where you are allowed to modify the tree.  But I did give 2 examples, so surely it has some :)  Anyway I modified my answer to take out the invalid parts.

Comment: For those without TAOCP, @AntonTykhyy is referring to the Morris tree traversal algorithms, which run in O(n) time and O(1) auxiliary space.   This page might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5502916/explain-morris-inorder-tree-traversal-without-using-stacks-or-recursion.  Also, someone posted the pre-order Morris algorithm below.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this if nodes have pointers to their parents. When you walk back up the tree (using the parent pointers) you also pass the node you're coming from. If the node you're coming from is the left child of the node you're now at, then you traverse the right child. Otherwise you walk back up to it's parent.

EDIT in response to the edit in the question: If you want to iterate through the whole tree, then no this is not possible. In order to climb back up the tree you need to know where to go. However, if you just want to iterate through a *single* path down the tree then this can be achieved in O(1) additional space. Just iterate down the tree using a while loop, keeping a single pointer to the current node. Continue down the tree until you either find the node you want or hit a leaf node.

EDIT: Here's code for the first algorithm (check the iterate_constant_space() function and compare to the results of the standard iterate() function):

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

/* Implementation of a binary search tree. Nodes are ordered by key, but also
 * store some data.
 */
struct BinarySearchTree {
  int key;      // they key by which nodes are ordered
  string data;  // the data stored in nodes
  BinarySearchTree *parent, *left, *right;   // parent, left and right subtrees

  /* Initialise the root
   */
  BinarySearchTree(int k, string d, BinarySearchTree *p = NULL)
    : key(k), data(d), parent(p), left(NULL), right(NULL) {};
  /* Insert some data
   */
  void insert(int k, string d);
  /* Searches for a node with the given key. Returns the corresponding data
   * if found, otherwise returns None."""
   */
  string search(int k);
  void iterate();
  void iterate_constant_space();
  void visit();
};

void BinarySearchTree::insert(int k, string d) {
  if (k <= key) { // Insert into left subtree
    if (left == NULL)
      // Left subtree doesn't exist yet, create it
      left = new BinarySearchTree(k, d, this);
    else
      // Left subtree exists, insert into it
      left->insert(k, d);
  } else { // Insert into right subtree, similar to above
    if (right == NULL)
      right = new BinarySearchTree(k, d, this);
    else
      right->insert(k, d);
  }
}

string BinarySearchTree::search(int k) {
  if (k == key) // Key is in this node
    return data;
  else if (k < key && left)   // Key would be in left subtree, which exists
    return left->search(k); // Recursive search
  else if (k > key && right)
    return right->search(k);
  return "NULL";
}

void BinarySearchTree::visit() {
  printf("Visiting node %d storing data %s\n", key, data.c_str());
}

void BinarySearchTree::iterate() {
  visit();
  if (left) left->iterate();
  if (right) right->iterate();
}

void BinarySearchTree::iterate_constant_space() {
  BinarySearchTree *current = this, *from = NULL;
  current->visit();
  while (current != this || from == NULL) {
    while (current->left) {
      current = current->left;
      current->visit();
    }
    if (current->right) {
      current = current->right;
      current->visit();
      continue;
    }
    from = current;
    current = current->parent;
    if (from == current->left) {
      current = current->right;
      current->visit();
    } else {
      while (from != current->left && current != this) {
        from = current;
        current = current->parent;
      }
      if (current == this && from == current->left && current->right) {
        current = current->right;
        current->visit();
      }
    }
  }
}

int main() {
  BinarySearchTree tree(5, "five");
  tree.insert(7, "seven");
  tree.insert(9, "nine");
  tree.insert(1, "one");
  tree.insert(2, "two");
  printf("%s\n", tree.search(3).c_str());
  printf("%s\n", tree.search(1).c_str());
  printf("%s\n", tree.search(9).c_str());
  // Duplicate keys produce unexpected results
  tree.insert(7, "second seven");
  printf("%s\n", tree.search(7).c_str());
  printf("Normal iteration:\n");
  tree.iterate();
  printf("Constant space iteration:\n");
  tree.iterate_constant_space();
}
```

Comment: "When you walk back up the tree"... how do you get to the bottom of each node in the tree?

Comment: current = root; while current->left exists: current = current->left

Comment: @marcog: Yes you can surely get to a single node.... But I said how do you get to the bottom of each node in the tree?

Comment: Using the condition I mentioned to go down the right child when you've just come up from the left child.

Comment: And once you process that right child, how do you get the the second left most child? and then the left most's right child? ... You need to store which paths you've taken.

Comment: Assume you're at the left-most leaf. Then you go up to its parent. Since you came up to the parent from it's left child, you go down to its right child. Assume for simplicity that this right child is also a leaf. You go back up to its parent. Since you came up to the parent from it's right child, you go up to the parent's parent. Using this algorithm you can traverse the entire tree without storing paths.

Comment: @Marco: this approach doesn't work, there's no place to remember whether you went left or right last time you visited the node. Try to code it up (I did).

Comment: @Anton Going from a child to it's parent you pass the address of the child to the parent. The parent then compares to it's pointer to the left child. If they're equal then you came from the left child, otherwise you came from the right child.

Comment: @Anton edited my answer to include code to prove it's possible :)

Answer (score 1):

Pointers from nodes to their ancestors can be had with no (well, two bits per node) additional storage using a structure called a threaded tree.  In a threaded tree, null links are represented by a bit of state rather than a null pointer. Then, you can replace the null links with pointers to other nodes: left links point to the successor node in an inorder traversal, and right links to the predecessor. Here is a Unicode-heavy diagram (X represents a header node used to control the tree):

```
                                         ╭─┬────────────────────────────────────────╮
   ╭─────────────────────────▶┏━━━┯━━━┯━━▼┓│                                        │
   │                        ╭─╂─  │ X │  ─╂╯                                        │ 
   │                        ▼ ┗━━━┷━━━┷━━━┛                                         │
   │                    ┏━━━┯━━━┯━━━┓                                               │
   │               ╭────╂─  │ A │  ─╂──╮                                            │
   │               ▼    ┗━━━┷━━━┷━━━┛  │                                            │    
   │        ┏━━━┯━━━┯━━━┓    ▲         │        ┏━━━┯━━━┯━━━┓                       │
   │      ╭─╂─  │ B │  ─╂────┤         ├────────╂─  │ C │  ─╂───────╮               │
   │      ▼ ┗━━━┷━━━┷━━━┛    │         ▼        ┗━━━┷━━━┷━━━┛       ▼               │  
   │┏━━━┯━━━┯━━━┓ ▲          │   ┏━━━┯━━━┯━━━┓       ▲         ┏━━━┯━━━┯━━━┓        │
   ╰╂─  │ D │  ─╂─╯          ╰───╂   │ E │  ─╂╮      │        ╭╂─  │ F │  ─╂╮       │ 
    ┗━━━┷━━━┷━━━┛                ┗━━━┷━━━┷━━━┛▼      │        ▼┗━━━┷━━━┷━━━┛▼       │
                                    ▲ ┏━━━┯━━━┯━━━┓  │ ┏━━━┯━━━┯━━━┓ ▲ ┏━━━┯━━━┯━━━┓│
                                    ╰─╂─  │ G │   ╂──┴─╂─  │ H │  ─╂─┴─╂─  │ J │  ─╂╯
                                      ┗━━━┷━━━┷━━━┛    ┗━━━┷━━━┷━━━┛   ┗━━━┷━━━┷━━━┛
```

Once you have the structure, doing an inorder traversal is very, very easy:

```
Inorder-Successor(p)
    p points to a node.  This routine finds the successor of p in
    an inorder traversal and returns a pointer to that node

    q ← p.right
    If p.rtag = 0 Then
        While q.ltag = 0 Do
            q ← q.left
        End While
    End If

    Return q
```

Lots more information on threaded trees can be found in *Art of Computer Programming* Ch.2 §3.1 or scattered around the Internet.

Answer (score 1):

"Datastructures and their algorithms" by Harry Lewis and Larry Denenberg describe link inversion traversal for constant space traversal of a binary tree. For this you do not need parent pointer at each node. The traversal uses the existing pointers in the tree to store path for back tracking. 2-3 additional node references are needed. Plus a bit on each node to keep track of traversal direction (up or down) as we move down. In my implementation of this algorithms from the book, profiling shows that this traversal has far less memory / processor time. An implementation in java is [here](http://harisankar-krishnaswamy.blogspot.in/2013/10/a-coder-post-link-inversion-traversal.html).

Comment: You need an extra data structure to hold that bit array, this isn't O(1) space.

Answer (score 0):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_linked_list

encode your parent node into the leaf pointers

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. Here is my example of the iteration which has the O(n) time complexity and O(1) space complexity.

```
using System;
                    
public class Program
{
    public class TreeNode {
      public int val;
      public TreeNode left;
      public TreeNode right;
      public TreeNode(int val=0, TreeNode left=null, TreeNode right=null) {
          this.val = val;
          this.left = left;
          this.right = right;
      }
    }
    public static void Main()
    {
        TreeNode left = new TreeNode(1);
        TreeNode right = new TreeNode(3);
        TreeNode root = new TreeNode(2, left, right);
        
        TreeNode previous = null;
        TreeNode current = root;
        TreeNode newCurrent = null;
        
        while(current != null) {
            if(current.left == null) {
                if(current.right == null) {
                    if(previous == null) {
                        Console.WriteLine(current.val);
                        break;
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine(current.val);
                    current = previous;
                    previous = previous.left;
                    current.left = null;
                } else {
                    newCurrent = current.right;
                    current.right = null;
                    current.left = previous;
                    previous = current;
                    current = newCurrent;
                }
            } else {
                newCurrent = current.left;
                current.left = previous;
                previous = current;
                current = newCurrent;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Each time you see the `Console.WriteLine(current.val);` is where you should put your code for the value processing.

Answer (score -2):

I think there's no way you could do this, as you should somehow find the nodes where you left off in a path and to identify that you always need O(height) space.

Answer (score -3):

Is it possible to iterate over a binary tree in O(1) auxiliary space.

```
struct node { node * father, * right, * left; int value; };
```

This structure will make you be able to move 1-step in any direction through the binary tree.
But still in iteration you need to keep the path!