# Iterating over AVL tree in O(1) space without recursion

Tags: c, algorithm, data-structures

I have an AVL Tree. Each node looks like this:

```
typedef struct {
    Node *parent;  // the parent node
    Node *left;    // the node left of this node
    Node *right;   // the node right of this node
    int height;    // the height of this node
    void *value;   // payload
} Node;
```

Is it possible to iterate over an AVL tree with these nodes in O(1) space, **without** recursion, if yes, how?

If not, a solution with sub-O(n) space or iff really necessary O(N) space is appreciated as well.

With iterating over the tree I mean I want to visit each node once, and if possible in order (from the mostleft to the mostright node).

Comment: Homework, right? What have you tried?

Comment: @Jim Balter: not homework, I wish. I'm 17 and still stuck in high-school (or at least the Dutch version of it). It's for a Python project, and it is used in an iterator.

Comment: In what way do you want to “iterate over an AVL tree”?

Comment: @Gumbo: Woops, forgot to say that in the question. I want to visit each node once, and if possible in order (from the mostleft to the mostright node).

Comment: Again, what have you tried? Surely you can at least find your way to the first (leftmost) node ... figure out what to do next.

Comment: How can iterating over a structure with `n` elements ever be more time-efficient than `O(n)`?!

Comment: @ThiefMaster: In space it's possible and even pretty easy. In time, you are right.

Comment: @ThiefMaster Read it again ... "**space**".

Comment: Ah, misread the question

Comment: @ThiefMaster: O(1) __space__, which means the algorithm uses a constant amount of memory, where an algorithm of O(n) __space__ uses an amount of memory linear to the the amount of elements. You are confusing space with execution speed.

Comment: @Jim Balter: I have only thought of (trivial) recursive solutions, and replacing that recursion with an explicit stack, but I can't seem to think of a solution that doesn't keep track of visited nodes somehow.

Comment: @Thief I made the same mistake in my head and have tried to pre-empt anyone else suffering with an edit :)

Comment: @nightcracker Did you think of, um, searching the web, even searching SO? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/791052/iterating-over-a-binary-tree-with-o1-auxiliary-space

Comment: Your struct does not compile as it is, because the typedefed `Node` is not useable inside your struct. Use: `typedef struct Node { struct Node *parent;...} Node;` instead.

Comment: @halex: Oh, I just wrote a pageholder on this quest, it wasn't meant to compile.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you store the last node you have visited, you can derive the next node to visit in an iterator.

- If the last node was your parent, go down the left subtree.
- If the last node was your left subtree, go down the right subtree.
- If the last node was your right subtree, go to your parent.

This algorithm gives you a traversal in O(1) for the tree. You need to flesh it out a little for the leaves and decide what kind of iterator (pre/in/post-order) you want to decide where the iterator should and wait for incrementation.

Comment: Of course! And this allows me to iterate over the tree in order by starting with the leftmost's-parent node and the last node set to the leftmost node. Thanks!

Comment: @nightcracker You can iterate over the tree by starting with the root node and the last node set to NULL (the root node's parent).

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to get the next in-order node given a pointer to some node, as long as you keep parent pointers. This can be used to iterate the tree, starting with the leftmost node. From [my implementation of AVL tree](http://code.google.com/p/badvpn/source/browse/trunk/structure/BAVL.h):

```
BAVLNode * BAVL_GetNext (const BAVL *o, BAVLNode *n)
{
    if (n->link[1]) {
        n = n->link[1];
        while (n->link[0]) {
            n = n->link[0];
        }
    } else {
        while (n->parent && n == n->parent->link[1]) {
            n = n->parent;
        }
        n = n->parent;
    }

    return n;
}
```

To get the leftmost node:

```
BAVLNode * BAVL_GetFirst (const BAVL *o)
{
    if (!o->root) {
        return NULL;
    }

    BAVLNode *n = o->root;
    while (n->link[0]) {
        n = n->link[0];
    }

    return n;
}
```

Here, `node->link[0]` and `node->link[1]` are the left and right child of the node, respectively, and `node->parent` is the pointer to the parent node (or `NULL` for root).

A single GetNext() operation has O(logn) time complexity. However, when used to iterate the entire tree, you get O(n) amortized time complexity.

Comment: This doesn't work. For instance, it returns NULL for any tree where the root has no right link.... Well, maybe it works with your edit, starting at the leftmost node.

Comment: It *does* work. If you call GetNext(root) and the root has no right link, then yes, it returns NULL - because the root is the *last node*, and there is no next node. An if you call GetNext(rightmost child of root's left child), it retuns the root (not NULL). Also, I've used that code in like 20 different places with no issues.

Comment: @Jim: obviously you have to start at the leftmost node, not the root, in order to iterate the tree in-order.

Comment: That is NOT obvious. See, for instance, thiton's answer and my comment on it.

Comment: @Jim: I mentioned at the beginning of my answer that GetNext() returns the next *in-order* node of the given node. It follows from this that you have to start with the node having least value, i.e. leftmost, in order to get all the nodes with repeated invocation of GetNext(). It's obvious the same way as it is that to iterate a *linked list* from start to finish, you have to start at the first node, not some middle node.

Comment: @Jim: also see how my way is generally more useful than thiton's, since it iterates *in-order*, which is needed in many cases. E.g. if you inserted integers into the tree, you can sort them just iterating the tree in-order.

Answer (score 0):

"Datastructures and their algorithms" by Harry Lewis and Larry Denenberg describe link inversion traversal for constant space traversal of a binary tree. For this you do not need parent pointer at each node. The traversal uses the existing pointers in the tree to store path for back tracking. 2-3 additional node references are needed. Plus a bit on each node to keep track of traversal direction (up or down) as we move down. In my implementation of this algorithms from the book, profiling shows that this traversal has far less memory / processor time. An implementation in java (c would be faster i guess) is [here](http://harisankar-krishnaswamy.blogspot.in/2013/10/a-coder-post-link-inversion-traversal.html).