# In-Order iteration over a Binary Tree with O(1) Auxiliary Space

Tags: c, binary-tree, tree-traversal

Well I know there is a post out there from '09, but I'm still not sure how to implement this. 
I didn't understand the solution that Anton gave here, also it is very old thread: [Iterating over a Binary Tree with O(1) Auxiliary Space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/791052/iterating-over-a-binary-tree-with-o1-auxiliary-space)

Thus, I hope after 8 years we can think of some other solutions, any help is much appreciated.

Note: It was an interview question for my friend, the hint was always knowing where we came from.

Comment: IMHO the answer in the linked post is cheating. Instead of keeping the memory in a stack (auxiliary or recursion), the author of the answer kelt it as an additional field in node. Another field to each node is O(n) space... As far as I know, you cannot traverse a binary with O(1) space without destroying the tree (as suggested in another answer)

Comment: "Thus, I hope after 8 years we can think of some other solutions", you will be surprise but no. We still waiting "The Art of Computer Programming 4B" :p.

Comment: @Stargateur haha that's a good one.